# Azure Hyperscale - How to reclaim unused allocated space

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Our DB has 3TB of data but allocated space is 4,5TB.

How to reduce space ?

MS documentation:
"DBCC SHRINKDATABASE or DBCC SHRINKFILE isn't currently supported for Hyperscale databases."

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE/DBCC SHRINKFILE

Answer (score 1):

Yes Shrink is not supported in Hyperscale as of now, so you cannot reduce the space currently as it is a complex task, only possible option is the logical data movement to another database